# Tee resets exit status is always 0

Tags: bash, shell, wait, tee

I have a short script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
<some_process> | tee -a /tmp/some.log  &
wait $(pidof <some_process_name>)
echo $?
```

The result is always 0, irrespective of the exit status of some_process.

**I know PIPESTATUS can be used here**, but why does tee **break *`wait`***?

Comment: You're checking the exit status of the last command which is the `wait` command. So if it's successfully finished, hence the exit status will be 0.

Comment: @AvihooMamka No, `wait` should return the exit status of the specified pid.

Comment: @YamMarcovic from the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) - Return Value: wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned.

Comment: @AvihooMamka You're looking at the docs of the system call, not the bash builtin.....

Comment: OK, from other [docs](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/wait): Return status:
The return status is the return status of the job waited for, or 
0 - waited for all jobs in shell's job list. 1 - the given ID is not a valid job or process ID

Comment: @AvihooMamka How is it not a valid process ID?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that the return status is 0 if "waited for all jobs in shell's job list".

Comment: @AvihooMamka But is that the case here? He waits on a specific pid.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Yes but the process is still attached to the shell's job list. He should `disown` the job.

Comment: @AvihooMamka But then he wouldn't be able to wait on it.

Comment: He would. The process is being moved to the background but still attached to the shell's job list.

Comment: @hek2mgl Please open this question. It's not a duplicate. He says he knows about PIPESTATUS, but is asking about combining it with `wait`.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Sorry, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is something that, for some peculiar reason, the docs don't mention. The code, however, does:

```
int wait_for (pid) { /*...*/
/* If this child is part of a job, then we are really waiting for the
job to finish. Otherwise, we are waiting for the child to finish. [...] */

if (job == NO_JOB)
  job = find_job (pid, 0, NULL);
```

So it's actually waiting for the whole job, which, as we know, normally yields the exit status of the last command in the chain.

To make matters worse, `$PIPESTATUS` can only be used with the last *foreground* command.

You can, however, utilize `$PIPESTATUS` in a subshell job, like this:

```
(<some_process> | tee -a /tmp/some.log; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}) &
# somewhere down the line:
wait %%<some_process>
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to *use* `$PIPESTATUS` but also `wait -n`:

Check this example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# start background task
(sleep 5 | false | tee -a /tmp/some.log ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[1]}) &

# foreground code comes here
echo "foo"

# wait for background task to finish
wait -n
echo $?
```

Comment: Good trick. I think you don't even need `-n` though, you can just give a specific jobspec.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Looks like without `-n`, `wait` would always return `0`. I admit the `help wait` does not say that. Let me investigate that.

Comment: Actually, this will block until the first job finishes. So I'm not sure this is useful.

Comment: `wait` is supposed to block. Am I missing something? Sure, in a real world program between the background task and the wait command other lines of code would appear.

Comment: It will block before wait. See my (edited) answer for a combination of your trick and the use of a subshell to actually get a nice outcome.

Comment: Oh sorry, missed the subshell here. Have it in my test!! :)

Comment: :) Also, you're losing the exit status now, but just returning 0/1. When in a subshell, you can simply exit with PIPESTATUS[N] (as in my answer =])

Comment: Combined forces, eh. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you always get an exit status of `0` is that the exit status returned is that of *the last command in the pipeline*, which is `tee`. By using a pipe, you eliminate the normal detection of exit status of `<some_command>`.

From the bash man page:

> The  return  status  of  a  pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the pipefail option is enabled.  If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit successfully.

So...  The following might be what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o pipefail
<some_command> | tee -a /tmp/some.log  &
wait %1
echo $?
```